# Guessing a code block's language for correct syntax highlighting

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I'm quite puzzled how the syntax highlighting feature here on SO works, but I have seen similar somewhere else. How does this work?

- Is there one parser which can parse multiple languages at once?
- Or, are several passes of different parsers needed and the best parsing result is used?
- Or, is only a shallow analysis performed and the language is then guessed based on heuristics?

And if one of these is true, how does it work?

Comment: These days SO just looks at the tags to determine the language, which probably doesn't help you much.

Comment: @sepp: Oh, lol. I hadn't even thought of that, but it's so obvious. It's like looking at the extension of a file. However, I'm still interested if it's possible to do it with no such knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) on Google Code.